# Modify or set global variable from within Find<package>.cmake file

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules

I'm striving to understand how to create / modify a global variable (whose prefix is not `<PACKAGE>_`) from within a `Find<package>.cmake` file, so that it can be shared among different modules and reused by the global `CMakeLists.txt`.

Let's say I have a `FindMyModule.cmake` file:

```
set (MyModule_include_dirs "...")  # <-- This is visible from CMakeLists.txt caller
set (LIBS_INCLUDE_DIRS "${LIBS_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${MyModule_include_dirs}") <-- This is not
```

In `CMakeLists.txt`

```
find_package(MyModule)
message("My Module include dirs: "${MyModule_include_dirs}) # <-- Prints "My Module include dirs: ..."
message("Libs include dirs: " ${LIBS_INCLUDE_DIRS}) # <-- Prints "Libs include dirs: "
```

Googling and *so-ing* around, I've tried `CACHE`, `INTERNAL` and `PARENT_SCOPE` but no successful result so far.

Comment: You forgot closing brace after `${MyModule_include_dirs`.

Comment: Right, corrected. But it wasn't the issue, it was just a slip. Thank you for having spotted it

Comment: You declare both variables - `MyModule_include_dirs` and `LIBS_INCLUDE_DIRS` - in the **same manner** (using `set()` command), so they should have the **same visibility**. E.g. they both are visible in the `CMakeLists.txt` which calls `find_package`. If they have different visibility, then ... you run not the code which you show us. E.g. you have another script `FindMyModule.cmake` somewhere, so `find_package(MyModule)` actually includes that other script. Have you tried to put the same `message` commands into `FindMyModule.cmake`?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand why would you want to change a global variable from within a `findXYZ.cmake` script, as you are tightly coupling other scripts to this script or visa versa.

If I recall correctly, as long as you set a variable as `CACHE INTERNAL` before you start processing anything it should be available at all time to **the following CMake instructions**. We could've fixed that **easily** if you'd provide a **minimal reproducible example**.

The other options that you have for "GLOBAL variables" is to use [`set_property()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html) i.e.:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY GLOBAL_LIBS_INCLUDE_DIR "${LIBS_INCLUDE_DIR} ${MyModule_include_dirs}")
```

And then everywhere else:

```
get_property(LIBS_INCLUDE_DIR GLOBAL PROPERTY GLOBAL_LIBS_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

To demonstrate that **BOTH WORK:**

*CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.20)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

project ("GlobalVariables")

set(CACHE_INTERNAL_VARIABLE "HELLO" CACHE INTERNAL "")
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY GLOBAL_PROPERTY_VARIABLE "HELLO ")

find_package(MODULE_VARIABLE MODULE)

get_property(GLOBAL_PROPERTY_VARIABLE GLOBAL PROPERTY GLOBAL_PROPERTY_VARIABLE)
message(STATUS ${GLOBAL_PROPERTY_VARIABLE})
message(STATUS ${CACHE_INTERNAL_VARIABLE})
```

*findMODULE_VARIABLE.cmake*

```
set(CACHE_INTERNAL_VARIABLE "${CACHE_INTERNAL_VARIABLE} WORLD" CACHE INTERNAL "")
get_property(TEMP GLOBAL PROPERTY GLOBAL_PROPERTY_VARIABLE)
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY GLOBAL_PROPERTY_VARIABLE "${TEMP} WORLD")
```

Both variables output the same:

```
-- HELLO WORLD
-- HELLO WORLD
```